# Dreamweaver ASP command INSERT INTO not passing value

Tags: sql, asp-classic, dreamweaver

Hi I am trying to create an INSERT INTO script in Dreamweaver Command and ASP.

If I use a static value it works fine, but when I try to declare a variable I get the following error message

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere]Primary key for table 'testing' 
is not unique 
/coding/Untitled-3.asp, line 30
```

Now the reason it is telling me the primary key is not unique is it is passing a null value, rather than the value of my field. Code below;

```html
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%

Dim Command1__product

Command1__product = Request.Form("product")

%>

<!--#include file="Connections/Conn_PSCRM_Demo.asp" -->
<%
' IIf implementation
Function MM_IIf(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse)
  If condition = "" Then
    MM_IIf = ifFalse
  Else
    MM_IIf = ifTrue
  End If
End Function
%>
<%

Set Command1 = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Command1.ActiveConnection = MM_Conn_PSCRM_Demo_STRING
Command1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testing (prodref)  VALUES (?)"
Command1.Parameters.Append Command1.CreateParameter("product", 201, 1, 25, MM_IIF(Request.Form("Field1") , Request.Form("Field1") , Command1__product & ""))
Command1.CommandType = 1
Command1.CommandTimeout = 0
Command1.Prepared = true
Command1.Execute()

%>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form">
  <label for="Field1"></label>
  <input name="Field1" type="text" id="Field1" value="33399">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My last asp code was years ago so I may be wrong - but - you are **executing your insert stmt every time your page loads** rather than **only** execute when **form was posted**! pls reply if I am mistaken...

Comment: You are correct! I have uploaded the incomplete code, but realising this I have also found the problem!

Comment: Glad I could help, please consider voting to vote up and/or select a given answer as best answer to mark this question as done!

Answer (score 1):

According to my comment - you'll have to **check if your form has been posted** or your site has just been initially loaded. In your question the code will be executed everytime the site has been loaded - that's why it works when you provide hardcoded values.

Anything like this code will do the trick

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
If Request.Form("SUBMITBUTTON") <> "" then
    Dim Command1__product
    Command1__product = Request.Form("product")
    ' all your code goes here!
%>
```

Answer (score -1):

Bit of a rookie error, I wasn't declaring the form variable.

I have added a Bindings Request.Form and all is working.